# Outside Union in R

Tags: r, matrix, union

I need to perform appears to be an union on two tables in R. However the union needs to include columns that are not common to the two parent matrices / tables.

This scenario looks very similar to the Outer Union described here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/what-is-outer-union-and-why-is-it-partially-compatible

I have two Matrices:

Matrix 1

```
Name Var1 Var2 
1    1    0 
2    1    0
```

Matrix 2

```
Name Var1 Var3
3    0    1
4    0    1
```

That I need to combine into Matrix 3:

```
Name Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    0    1
4    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution using `merge`

```
M <- replace(M<-as.matrix(merge(data.frame(M1),data.frame(M2),all = T)),
        which(is.na(M)),
        0)
```

such that

```
> M
     Name Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    2    1    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    1
[4,]    4    0    0    1
```

**DATA**

```
M1 <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Name", "Var1", "Var2")))

M2 <- structure(c(3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Name", "Var1", "Var3")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `data.frame` and use `bind_rows`.  By default, it fills the missing values with `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(as.data.frame(m1), as.data.frame(m2)) %>%
    mutate_all(replace_na, 0) %>%
    as.matrix
#      Name Var1 Var2 Var3
#[1,]    1    1    0    0
#[2,]    2    1    0    0
#[3,]    3    0    0    1
#[4,]    4    0    0    1
```

Or as @markus mentioned `rbind.fill.matrix` from `plyr` would be useful

```
plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(m1, m2)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Name", "Var1", "Var2")))

m2 <- structure(c(3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Name", "Var1", "Var3")))
```